# Configure Power BI Service Paginated Report Database Connection

Tags: powerbi, connection-string, powerbi-paginated-reports

Tried to deploy paginated report to Power BI service. But could not find a way to configure the database connection string under Pro license

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be changed in the portal after deployment.  So either update and redeploy the RDL or update it using the API [Reports - Update Datasources In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/update-datasources-in-group).